# How to remove default headers and author information but keep line numbers in acmart document class

Tags: latex, tex, overleaf

I am working with overleaf latex using

```
\documentclass[sigconf,authordraft]{acmart}
```

I need

1. To include line numbers for the two column document
2. To remove author information which comes as page header.

I tried

```
\documentclass[sigconf,authordraft]{acmart}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} 
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} 
\pagestyle{plain}
```

but its not removing the headers.

Any ideas please.

Answer (score -1):

I sorted this out by using     \documentclass[sigconf,anonymous, review]{acmart}    though the headers are default for ACM.